# jQuery: unselect option in select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I faced with a strange behaviour of select element. So, I have a select element with several options. One of option is empty - it's required by plugin to output placeholder.

I needed functionality that would clear selected options and I wrote something like:

```
$(element).val('');
$(element).find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
```

The thing is that "selected" attribute is still here and it's on old option - you can see it in the code sample.

So, I have 2 questions:

1) Why .val() method of jQuery library do not update "selected" attribute in options list?

2) Why I can not update "selected" attribute in my case? If I switch these statements it's working:

```
$(element).find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
$(element).val('');
```

Code sample:

```js
$(function(){


  $("#unselect").click(function(){
    
    $("#lang_type").val('');
    $("#lang_type").find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
    alert($("#lang_type").html());
    
  });




});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lang_type">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="01">01 - Language of text</option>
<option value="02">02 - Original language of a translated text</option>
<option selected="selected" value="03">03 - Language of abstracts</option>
<option value="04">04 - Rights language</option>
<option value="05">05 - Rights-excluded language</option>
<option value="06">06 - Original language in a multilingual edition</option>
<option value="07">07 - Translated language in a multilingual edition</option>
<option value="08">08 - Language of audio track</option>
<option value="09">09 - Language of subtitles</option>
</select>

<button id="unselect">Unselect</button>
```

Comment: I think it is because you are first doing ```.val()``` which is selecting the empty option and then it is selecting the empty element, but in second, you are doing vice versa .. just a guess

Comment: The `.val()` is selecting the first option... in memory. The HTML content never changes, because, that's just the initial state of the page when loaded. Don't worry about what the HTML shows; worry about what the result is.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** 
You can use `prop(false)` property like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/rn0eoqcn/3/)

```
$(function(){
  $("#unselect").click(function(){    
    $("#lang_type").val('');
    $("#lang_type").find("option:selected").prop('selected',false);
  });
});
```

Like @yezzz said, read this :
**Note: Do not use removeProp() method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.**

Comment: In Firefox 58.0.1 (64-bit), I was able to dynamically remove a selected property from an option in a multi-select menu. First, I tested to see if it was already selected: $(selectMenu option[value="somevalue"]).attr('selected', true);   Then, I removed it with this: $(selectMenu option[value="somevalue"]).prop('selected', false);

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, a multi-select can be initially unselected, but once any option is selected, it can not be unselected any more. [RFC 1866](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt) states in section 8.1.3:

> The initial state has the first option selected, unless a SELECTED attribute is present on any of the  elements.

This lets me to believe that one option MUST always be selected. Obviously, different browsers interpret this differently...

But it does not seem to be a jQuery issue, rather a browser implementation issue.

Comment: You're right, thank you! I've added empty option without value and when I want to deselect all, I select this empty option with jquery.

Answer (score 0):

The `selected` attribute reflects merely the initial state of the select input. You shouldn't really care about removing it, as it affects nothing once a different option is selected (either by the user or by a script on your page).

The current state of the input can be read or modified via the `selectedIndex` property, where a value of `-1` means no option is selected (which never is the default, as there always is an option selected initially). However, you seem to want to select a particular "empty" option.
Setting the value on a select box results in the corresponding option being selected, which, in your case, is the very first one.

The code probably *does exactly what you want*. So don't mind checking the HTML, as the `selected` attribute - again - is unrelated to the current state of the input.

The `:selected` selector, however, matches the elements that are *currently* selected. Your first snippet selects an option, thus making it `:selected`, then attempts to remove a non-existent attribute from it. The second snippet of yours assumes that the selection remains on the option that was initially selected, and then removes the attribute from it. What follows is the "empty" option getting selected, and no more steps need to be taken, as that's all it takes to *select* an option.

To summarize: you can safely drop all the code that deals with the removal of the `selected` attribute, as it doesn't affect the current state of the element, the state being already tied to the correct option.